# no-unused-vars in Vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Module build failed because of the following eslint errors:
the below code is giving me an error which i am not able to track

```
TM_onLoadPopupPromoBox: function() {
            var $modal = $('.on-pageload-popup-promobox');
            if( $modal.length > 0 ) {
                $modal.each( function(){
                    var $current_item       = $(this);
                    var target              = $current_item.data('target');
                    var timeout             = $current_item.data('timeout');

                    var delay               = $current_item.data('delay');
                    delay = ( !delay ) ? 2500 : Number(delay) + 2500;

                    if( $current_item.hasClass('cookie-enabled') ) {
                        var elementCookie = $.cookie( target );
                        if ( !!elementCookie && elementCookie === 'enabled' ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $.removeCookie( target );
                    }

                    var t_enablepopup = setTimeout(function() {
                        $.magnificPopup.open({
                            items: { src: target },
                            type: 'inline',
                            mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-fade',
                            closeBtnInside: false,
                            fixedContentPos: true,
                            removalDelay: 500,
                            callbacks: {
                                afterClose: function() {
                                    if( $current_item.hasClass('cookie-enabled') ) {
                                        $.cookie( target, 'enabled' );
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, 0);
                    }, Number(delay) );

                    if( timeout !== '' ) {
                        var t_closepopup = setTimeout(function() {
                            $.magnificPopup.close();
                        }, Number(delay) + Number(timeout) );
                    }
                });
            }
        },
```

**The errors:**
I am having so many errors 't_enablepopup' is assigned a value but never used

could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

you're declaring one parameter you're not using, remove the selectedData:

```
onSelected: function(){
                        $("#"+id+ " .dd-selected-value").prop ('name', name);      
                      },
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring this function:

```js
onSelected: function(selectedData)
```

You are passing the parameter `selectedData`. However, this parameter is never used in the following function, so an error appeared. You can just remove that parameter from the function to get rid of any errors.

```js
onSelected: function()
```